# (Tabbar hide) when the user go to next screen from Tabbar in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

Currently i am working in Android application, Using Tabbar to set five tabs, then i select third tab it shows ListView, the user select ListItem to go next screen (Using Intent), At the same time Tabbar is hidden, so i tried to show the tabbar in that screen, but i didn't know that? please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please give som example for this?

Comment: [Have a look at this example](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd been also having the same problem. With use of [this](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) `ActivityGroup` class help me to do my requirement. You can also try with below code.

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

    private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * This is called when a child activity of this one calls its finish method. 
     * This implementation calls {@link LocalActivityManager#destroyActivity} on the child activity
     * and starts the previous activity.
     * If the last child activity just called finish(),this activity (the parent),
     * calls finish to finish the entire group.
     */
  @Override
  public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
      LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
      int index = mIdList.size()-1;

      if (index < 1) {
          finish();
          return;
      }

      manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
      mIdList.remove(index); index--;
      String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
      Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
      Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
      setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
  }

  /**
   * Starts an Activity as a child Activity to this.
   * @param Id Unique identifier of the activity to be started.
   * @param intent The Intent describing the activity to be started.
   * @throws android.content.ActivityNotFoundException.
   */
  public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
      Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
      if (window != null) {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }    
  }

  /**
   * The primary purpose is to prevent systems before android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
   * from calling their default KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK during onKeyDown.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  /**
   * Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
   * so that all systems call onBackPressed().
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          onBackPressed();
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }

  /**
   * If a Child Activity handles KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
   * Simply override and add this method.
   */
  @Override
  public void  onBackPressed  () {
      int length = mIdList.size();
      if ( length > 1) {
          Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
          current.finish();
      }  
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Minu You've one example on that link. Try that example.

Comment: But already i have used ListActivity in 3rd Tab, then hoe to change ActivityGroup.

Comment: @Minu Is that giving any error using `ActivityGroup` instead of `ListActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

Activity1 that contain your list

```
    Activity1 extends ActivityGroup {

    ......

    yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
    Intent activity2Intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
    StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
    replaceContentView("activity2", activity2Intent);
    }
                        });
}
```

and Activity2 must extends Activity

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
........
}
```

look at this example [here](http://gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity)

try to create your listadapter as separate class like this

```
public class YourListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    List<String> values;

    public YourListAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {

        this.values = values;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return values.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourListRow, null);

        TextView txtTitre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowTxt);
        txtTitre.setText( values.get(position););

        return v;
    }
}
```

in your activity call your adapter for  fill your list

```
yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
YourListAdapter lAdapter= new YourListAdapter(YourActivity.this, YourListStrings);
yourListView.setAdapter(lAdapter);
```

Comment: But already i have used ListActivity in 3rd Tab, then hoe to change ActivityGroup

Comment: I edited my answer, look how to keep extending ActivityGroup and use ListView

Comment: I have one doubt, if multiple next screen means , how to handle this

Comment: the first activity that appear on tab must extends ActivityGroup(Activity that contain list in your case), for the others just make extends Activity

Comment: Now i used this procedur but the tabbar hide, please help me